# Using UUID in training datasets

Tags: machine-learning, dataset, training-data

I'm quite new to create predictive models,

is that possible to use a dataset w/ UUIDs to create a model, and once model's ready, predict a subset w/ UUID.

Here's an example 
COL1, COL2, PARAM1
4e259802-3b80-4e55, 48a9f0af-0c83-4766-a5af, 1a844429-b829-4545
..
..

I'd like to give a parameter to my model and get a result with UUIDs.
PARAM1 : 1a844429-b456-4545 -> MODEL -> PREDICTED::COL1: 4e349802-3b80-4e55, COL2:...

Is that possible to do that this way, or I've to transform/flatten my dataset with only float values which will correspond to my UUID ?

Thanks in advance.